# Space between in desktop, stacked on mobile how to?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

At the moment I'm using flex with `justify-content: center;` and padding left on B component. Is a temporary hack. How can I do it to work properly?

When the container is big, I want them centred but with a space in the middle. When is small, I would like to have them to go on top of each other.

Note:

- On the large screen the 2 items are centred and have a gap between.
- Should not be based on the screen size because the wrapper can be small on a desktop for example.
- No JS solution like component media query;

One of the solutions could be something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-element-query but uses JS.

[image]

Media query doesn't work because https://jsfiddle.net/t4j6z7og/

[image]

Comment: Just use bootstrap's columns.  They resize the content based on the screen size

Comment: what code have you tried??

Comment: Is not screen size, is parent size I'm looking for.

Comment: What is your current CSS and HTML?  Are you stacking them at a certain screen width?  If you are, you could have a CSS class for the gap that only applies over that screen size.

Comment: I wanted to avoid basing on screen size because the parent component might be small even if the screen is big.

Comment: share your current code,, at least part of it

Comment: Have you tried using media query?

Comment: Is just a wrapper div, 2 childs, the parent has flex and the 2nd child has a padding left of 20px. Nothing fancy really. I wanted to avoid any js like component media query.

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply make use of a media query to swap to **[`flex-direction: column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)** at the smaller width, and swap the margin for `B` from **[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left)** to **[`margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top)**?

This can be seen in the following example
(hit 'Run code snippet' then 'Full page' for the side-by-side view):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.a, .b {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.b {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .b {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Because the wrapper can be small on a big screen.

Comment: Then use units based on viewport size rather than pixels, such as `vw`.

Comment: That's still doesn't fix it. The parent wrapper can have 2 different sizes based on other elements on the page. The `vw` solution doesn't help.

Comment: @Totty.js -- So you have a wrapper that can be small... and depends on other elements? I don't see how that makes a difference if you just use a fixed media query breakpoint and percentage-based measurements for the flex. Perhpas if you showcase your code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, **clearly** stating all constraints and caveats, then I'll understand you better. But as far as I'm aware, my code completely emulates your question's diagram.

Comment: I added a screenshot, I will do an example.

Comment: I'm afraid your above link appears to show it working absolutely perfectly for me. Your box changes the gap in between the two elements, and proceeds to stack correctly, does it not? Still not sure how exactly this doesn't answer the question, though it seems to have gotten a downvote.

Comment: The downvote is not from me. The elements stack, but they shouldn't, that's the problem. There is enough space for them to stay on the same line. Notice the white container is the same width and the children stack even if not needed.